# Issues with System.Net.Http.dll

Tags: c#, .net, http, json.net

I'm having issues referring to System.Net.Http.dll version 4.2.0.0

Here is my setup -

> Visual Studio 2017, 15.8.7
>
> A simple console application targeting .net 4.7.2

When I create a new project, by default it has a reference to `System.Net.Http.dll` and the location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll`.

But when I execute my code,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assembly = GetAssemblyNameContainingType(typeof(HttpClient).FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("Path: " + assembly.Location);
        Console.WriteLine("Version: " + assembly.GetName().Version);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static Assembly GetAssemblyNameContainingType(String typeName)
    {
        foreach (Assembly currentassembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            Type t = currentassembly.GetType(typeName, false, true);
            if (t != null)
            { return currentassembly; }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I get the below output

```
  Path: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll
  Version: 4.0.0.0
```

It seems to pick up reference to `System.Net.Http.dll` from GAC instead of the `Programs Files (x86)` folder.

I specifically need reference to 4.2.0.0 - since it addresses serialization of `HttpRequestException` in a way Newtonsoft json can serialize and deserialize it without erroring out.

I read quite a few posts about others facing an issue with `System.Net.Http.dll`, many of those said that this was addressed in Visual Studio 2017, 15.8 and that one won't have to add reference to the `System.Net.Http` nugets and should let visual studio to refer it appropriately from framework.

Am i missing something?
I have tried numerous things -

Adding reference path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2) in project properties - did not help

Adding reference using path to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll - did not help

Copy local - True - did not help

Specific version - True - did not help

Added binding redirect - did not help. Gave below exception

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)'

Unchecked Auto-generate binding redirects in project properties - did not help

Unchecked Auto-generate binding redirects with manual binding redirect - did not help

Unchecked Auto-generate binding redirects with manual binding redirect + copy local - did not help

Adding a hint path - did not help
    
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll

Here is my .csproj (original, reverted after doing all above changes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{EEE1B52B-0316-4EB5-9F3B-383E377964BE}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>SysNetHttpTests</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>SysNetHttpTests</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: have you tried manually adding a ref? - please post your `csproj` xml

Comment: @JohnB, yes. I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem and suggested known solutions didn't work for me as well. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22781 So, I submitted a new issue as it was suggested https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [MS answer](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33034) (by Jose Perez Rodriguez):

> This is by design. Due to a Windows requirement, all of the framework
>   assemblies installed in the GAC need to be versioned 4.0.0.0. The
>   actual implementation contained in that assembly is not the 4.0.0.0
>   implementation but the 4.2.0.0 instead. There are a bunch of
>   complicated reasons of why Windows has this requirement on our
>   assemblies installed on the GAC, like servicing, bugfixing, and just
>   having one GAC for all .NET 4+ frameworks, but essentially this is
>   expected.

While you think it is 4.0 it's in fact 4.2. [Dll hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379287/i-keep-hearing-about-dll-hell-what-is-this), welcome back!